# Camera Movement on the Y axis

Tags: java, opengl, camera, game-physics

I have a camera in **OpenGL** and it can move on the X and Z axises.

You can **rotate** the camera with the **left and right arrow buttons** and **move forward, backward, left and right** with the **WASD buttons**. Here is the method for movement.

```
public void move(float amount, float dir) {
    z += amount * Math.sin((Math.toRadians(ry + 90 * dir)));
    x += amount * Math.cos((Math.toRadians(ry + 90 * dir)));
}
```

"*amount*" is the speed and "*dir*" is either "0" or "1" so it sets "90" to "0" or leaves it as "90". "*z*" is the position on the z axis. So as "*x*" and "*y*". "*rz*" is rotation on the z axis. So as "*rx*" and "*ry*".

With these, I **can not** move on the Y axis, which is UP and DOWN. I managed to add the rotation code to make the camera *LOOK* **UP** and **DOWN** but I can't make the camera go where you are *LOOKING* at. Here is the rotation method:

```
public void rotate(float amount, float way) {
    if (way == ROTATE_RIGHT)
    ry += amount;
    else if (way == ROTATE_LEFT)
    ry -= amount;
    if (way == ROTATE_UP && rx >= -90)
    rx -= amount;
    else if (way == ROTATE_DOWN && rx <= 90)
    rx += amount;
}
```

This is how I call the move() method.

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
    cam.move(0.01f, Camera.MOVE_STRAIGHT);

if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
    cam.move(-0.01f, Camera.MOVE_STRAIGHT);

if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
    cam.move(0.01f, Camera.MOVE_STRAFE);

if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
    cam.move(-0.01f, Camera.MOVE_STRAFE);
```

**Camera.MOVE_STRAIGHT = 1** and **Camera.MOVE_STRAFE = 0** and **cam is a Camera object.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1**: Forgot about changing X/Z movement. This should fix those issues.

**Edit 2**: Changed `amount` to `walkAmount` and `strafeAmount` for both types of horizontal movement. `y` now also uses `walkAmount`.

**Edit 3**: Added `move()`

```
public void move(float amount, float dir) {
    /* If you are moving straight ahead, or in reverse, modify the Y value for ascent/descent
     * Since you do not change your elevation if you are strafing, dir will be 0. sin(0) = 0, and the elevation will not change (regardless of whether rx is 0).
     * When you are moving forward or in reverse, dir will be 1, so the rotation about the x axis will be used, and the elevation will change (unless rx is 0).
     */
    y += amount * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rx) * dir);

    /* If you are moving straight ahead, or in reverse, scale the delta X/Z (what comes after the +=) so that you don't move as far.
     * For example, if you are aimed straight up, and you move straight ahead (W/S), Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rx) * dir) will evaluate to 0, since you only want to move in the Y direction.
     * If you are aimed perfectly straight ahead (rotation about the x axis is 0), and you move straight ahead (A/D), Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rx) * dir) will evalute to 1, and your X/Z
     * movement would use the entire amount, since you are no longer moving in the Y direction.
     * If you are strafing (A/D), dir will be 0, and Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rx) * dir) will evalute to 1 (cos(0) == 1)). You will ONLY move in the X/Z directions when strafing.
     */
    z += amount * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rx) * dir) * Math.sin((Math.toRadians(ry + 90 * dir)));
    x += amount * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rx) * dir) * Math.cos((Math.toRadians(ry + 90 * dir)));
}
```

Please let me know if this helps you or if you have any issues.

Comment: Almost works. The problem is, when I am looking directly down or directly up, and try to go directly up or down, the x and z axises change a little causing the camera to move slightly to forwards or backwards.

Comment: @Sierox Sorry about that! I forgot about scaling the X/Z movement. I added the change for those two lines to my answer.

Comment: Now when I look directly down/up and try to go directly LEFT/RIGHT, I move directly UP/DOWN.

Comment: You should probably use two different amount values then. One for strafing (left to right) and one for walking/backpedaling (front/back). I'm adding more code to my answer.

Comment: @Sierox I do have a question though, what exactly have you been assigning to your `amount` variable up until now?

Comment: Its a float and is assigned to 0.01f everytime you move (for now) and when increased, the movement speed is to be increased. (Since I didn't set an FPS and that it is around 1000, 0.01 is an ideal speed for testing.)

Comment: @Sierox Ok, wherever you get the key state information, I suggest having `walkAmount` for W/S and `strafeAmount` for A/D in addition to `amount`. You can use `amount` for your rotation and set every time as it is, and `walkAmount` and `strafeAmount` should be zero unless one of the W/S is pressed for `walkAmount` and A/D for `strafeAmount`.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause ONLY x or ONLY y movement? Because If you are looking somewhere between x and y and if you press W since A/D aren't pressed wouldn't you go on only X or Y?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more detailed? I couldn't exactly understand what I am supposed to do. I am executing all these code in 2 methods inside my camera class. One is for movement and the other is for rotation.

Comment: @Sierox Do you mind posting both methods? I could more easily find an implementation that fits your needs that way.

Comment: I added the methods as an edit. If needed I can add the way they are called.

Comment: @Sierox Could you do that? Specifically for the `move()` method.

Comment: I added every call made for running the move() method as an edit.

Comment: @Sierox Ok, I went and rewrote your `move()` method to include the modified code for movement based on rotation. I added comments so it should help your through most of it. If you have any questions that my comments do not answer, please tell me.